# Strange behaviour of Shell.Current.GotoAsync. It does nothing at certain circumstances

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a .NET 8 MAUI project.

I have a loading page that has this code in `OnNavigatedTo` override:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        if (await App.IsAuthenticated())
        {
            await HeaderUtil.AddUserInfoAsync();
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(MainPage)}");
        }
        else
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(LoginPage)}");
        }
    });
}
```

You can see that I am checking whether user is logged in or not. It he is not, `LoginPage` is shown.

That code works, however, if I change that override to

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(LoginPage)}");
    });
}
```

`LoadingPage` is shown forever (and `LoginPage` constructor is never called).

What is it going on here?

A sample project is here: https://github.com/jaimestuardo/Test

Comment: 1. Why you do the Shell Navigation in `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` ? 2. You need to register all the routes not only for the page `CaptureCardPage` and `RegisterPage` in `AppShell.xaml.cs`.

Comment: You may try reigistering the page as [transient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#registration) instead of singleton.